# htaccess subdomain redirection at multiple levels

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I have this rule in my htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|cdn)\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user/%1/$1
```

right now http://username.domain.com/ works good, internally redirects to http://domain.com/user/username.
My goal is to redirect everything inside "user" folder, obtaining something like this http://username.domain.com/subfolder2/sybfolder3/ that redirects internally to http://domain.com/user/username/subfolder2/subfolder3/

Comment: But your rule is already doing this.

Comment: now i realized that my rule, as well as the Prix rule, works but without the trailing slash at the end of the url...